# Bounding Sphere for Two Hyperrectangles

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Please see the image for best illustration of the task. 
[image]

I have two hyperrectangles, $\text{R1}$ and $\text{R2}$, whose exact location and size is arbitrary. Now, my task is to construct a bounding circle, something like $\text{C4}$, such that its area includes any other circle formed by any of the edges of the rectangles (like $\text{C2}$ or $\text{C3}$).

My initial attempt was to construct a bounding rectangle that includes $\text{R1}$ and $\text{R2}$ and draw a circle $\text{C1}$ with the radius set to half the width of the longest distance between its edges. But as the drawing shows, that would ignore parts of the areas of $\text{C2}$ and $\text{C3}$.

Is there a mathematical way to determine a minimal radius value for the bounding circle $\text{C4}$ that would cover all the inner circles. Also, I am working in the multidimensional space, so the solution should not restrict itself to $2$ dimensions.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very knowledgeable in this subject, but [it appears that a general version of this question is a hard problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere).

Note that all of the points of a hyperrectangle will be inside the hypersphere iff each of their vertices are inside the hypersphere. Using we can convert our problem into a standard bounding sphere problem with $2\times 2^d$ points where $d$ is the dimension of the hyperrectangles. It appears that there are [several algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere#Algorithms) for this problem of varying degrees of expected closeness to optimality. It's possible that there is a better method given that you have hyperrectangles, but I couldn't find any.

Note that you can at least get trivial bounds on the size of the sphere - the upper bound given by the method you describe to find $\text{C1}$, and the lower bound given by a sphere having a radius of half the largest distance between the $2\times2^d$ points.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Peter. 

Instead setting the radius of the bounding circle C1 to the half of the longest distance of the compound box edges, I now set it to the full distance (do not divide by half). I believe, although it is not the tightest boundary, the resulting circumference of the C1 should contain all the other possible circles that could be formed by other edges of the compound rectangle. 

Do you think it's mathematically correct?

Comment: @d56 It's not good enough for when the dimension is bigger than $4$. In general for your way, if $s$ is the sidelength and $d$ is the dimension, you would need a hypercircle of radius $\frac{s}{2}\sqrt{d}$ (provided it is centered at the center of the hyperrectangle).

Comment: could you maybe provide a link where this equation is given? 
But i don't quite get it, it seems counterintuitive at least. If i have a point centered at the hyperrectangle why wouldn't the twice the distance between the point and the most remote point in the hyperrectangle be sufficient to include all the the possible alternative circles?

Comment: @d56 I think there might have been some misunderstanding. The formula I gave above is for when $s$ is the longest sidelength. If you are just taking the distance from the center of the hyperrectangle to the farthest point and then doubling it as I now think you are doing, then that's completely fine. I'll add why the formula I gave for radius given sidelength works in the next comment.

Comment: @d56 You can see the formula works by centering the hyperrectangle at the origin and so the furthest away points from the origin could at most be at $\left(\pm\frac{s}{2},\pm\frac{s}{2},\dots,\pm\frac{s}{2}\right)$. If we now use the distance formula to find the distance of one of these points from the origin, we get $$r=\sqrt{\frac{s^2}{4}+\dots+\frac{s^2}{4}}=\sqrt{\frac{ds^2}{4}}=\frac{s}{2} \sqrt{d}$$